# implements directive does not work in 64 bit version

Tags: delphi, interface, delegation, implements

In Delphi, you can delegate the implementation of an interface to a class property.
In the example, the TImplementator class implements the IImplementsInterface contract, aggregating the class - its real implementer (TImplementsForm), also monitoring its lifetime.
The ButtonTestClick method shows that this works (for a long time, with dozens of interfaces) under Win32. Under Win64, calling procedures works, when calling functions we get an exception (AV)

```
  IImplementsInterface = interface
    ['{8E978167-9C0C-414F-BBE8-037D6D865575}']
    function GetResultAV: Integer;
    procedure TestOk;
  end;

  TImplementsForm = class(TForm, IImplementsInterface)
    ButtonTest: TButton;
    procedure ButtonTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    { IImplementsInterface }
    function GetResultAV: Integer;
    procedure TestOk;
  public
  end;

  TComponentAggregator<T: TComponent> = class(TInterfacedObject)
  private
    FComponent: T;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TCustomImplementator<T: TComponent> = class(TComponentAggregator<T>, IImplementsInterface)
  private
    function GetImplementator: IImplementsInterface;
  protected
    property Implementator: IImplementsInterface read GetImplementator implements IImplementsInterface;
  end;

  TImplementator = class(TCustomImplementator<TImplementsForm>, IImplementsInterface);

var
  ImplementsForm: TImplementsForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TComponentAggregator<T> }

constructor TComponentAggregator<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FComponent := T.Create(nil);
end;

destructor TComponentAggregator<T>.Destroy;
begin
  FComponent.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

{ TImplementator }

function TCustomImplementator<T>.GetImplementator: IImplementsInterface;
begin
  Supports(FComponent, IImplementsInterface, Result);
end;

{ TImplementsForm }

procedure TImplementsForm.ButtonTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var LImplementsInterface: IImplementsInterface := TImplementator.Create; // LImplementsInterface - TImplementator as IImplementsInterface
  LImplementsInterface.TestOk;     // Ok x32, ok x64
  var LResult := LImplementsInterface.GetResultAV; // Ok x32, ACCESS_VIOLATION x64
end;

function TImplementsForm.GetResultAV: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
end;

procedure TImplementsForm.TestOk;
begin
  ShowMessage('TImplementsForm.Test');
end
```

How to achieve results under Win64

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: I used the entire line of Delphi 11 and Delphi 12

Comment: I added a Delphi 10.3.3 check - the result is the same.
After calling the interface method, it executes
mov [rbp+$34],eax
Wherein
rbp = 0000000000000000

Comment: I added a Delphi 10.4.1 check - the result is the same
Win32 - ok

Answer (score 4):

To be precise: the AV does not happen in the line you marked but after it during the epilogue of the method when the `LImplementsInterface` variable is about to get cleared.

Stepping through the code makes me believe this is some compiler glitch but I am not completely certain.

Anyhow: the implementation of `IImplementsInterface` in this line is superfluous and leads to this issue:

```
TImplementator = class(TCustomImplementator<TImplementsForm>, IImplementsInterface);
```

The interface was already implemented in the generic `TCustomImplementator<T>` class and the code will just work (*) when you remove it from `TImplementator`.

(*) as in there won't be an AV - you still have a memory leak because by using interface delegation you are also delegating the `_AddRef`/`_Release` calls and you are delegating them to a `TComponent` instance - that means you are leaking the `TComponentAggregator` instance that wraps your `TComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Here the re-declaration of the interface is done in order to get the correct link on the left side, and not the TComponent.
This works in Win32. And yes, I think you're right, it's a compiler error. Maybe with your authority we can reach out and fix it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).